# Not able add state in StateListDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout

In adapter class, i want to highlight the view but i am not able to do. Following are the code that i have used :

```java
StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, new ColorDrawable(Color.CYAN) );
stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled, android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));
stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{}, new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
Log.e("State ",""+stateListDrawable.getState().length );
```

**-> in log display state 0**

Comment: try `getStateCount`

Comment: don't have this method

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable#getStateCount()

Comment: anyway, your state is added, believe me - you can double check it using the debugger

Comment: ok, I assume state is added but not highlight the layout

Comment: did you call `View#setBackground`?

Comment: I use this: holder.setSelectionModeBackgroundDrawable(getHighlightedBackground());